# How to download all files in a directory in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, download

I am currently learning uploading / downloading / deleting files in C# asp.net. I figured out how to delete every file in a folder with code like this:

```
protected void DeleteAllFiles(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Output"));
    
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        dir.Delete(true);
    }

    Response.Redirect("~/Outputs.aspx?ReturnPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()));
}
```

But I can't find anything on how to download all files in a directory. I figured out how to download individual files but I am having trouble with a button that downloads all files in a directory. Surely there is an easy way to do this? I can't find it anywhere else so this is probably a dumb question to ask but any help is appreciated.

Comment: So think of it not as 'downloading' files, but 'copying' files and you'll be able to find what you're looking for. The answer is simple and you want to learn, so I suggest you take a look at this documentation and the answer should become clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.copyto?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you actually want to download a file from a website, that's a whole other thing including sending web requests, which it's probably worth looking at a guide on, this is probably one of the more simple guides, but learning more about HttpRequests in general will help you https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/how-to-download-files-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's not possible to send multiple files in a single HTTP request.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22413786/3571248) However, you can create a zip archive of multiple files and send that instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/681956/3571248) for an example.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have learned a lot and I did not know this. I figured out how to make a zip file and download that instead. Thanks again!